# Need help turning this function into a custom function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have this df with 4 columns: Name, screen_date, enroll_date, and screen2enroll_days

| Name | screen_date | enroll_date | screen2enroll_days | enrollment_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2020-08-20 | 2020-08-01 | 14 | TypeX |
| Mike | 2020-08-20 | 2020-08-01 | 14 | TypeY |
| Sam | 2020-10-20 | 2020-08-05 | 65 | TypeY |
| Dan | 2020-11-05 | 2020-08-05 | 90 | TypeX |

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    "Name" = c("John", "Mike", "Sam", "Dan"),
    "screen_date" = c("2020-08-01", "2020-08-20", "2020-10-20", "2020-11-05"),
    "enroll_date" = c("2020-08-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-05"),
    "screen2enroll_days" = c(14, 14, 65, 90),
    "enrollment_type" = c("TypeX", "TypeY", "TypeY", "TypeX")
  )
```

I want to create a function to read in one or more of my columns and create a new column called **Action** that uses the column **screen2enroll_days** to identify if a client needs a screening test. But ran into errors

| Name | screen_date | enroll_date | screen2enroll_days | Action (new_col) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2020-08-14 | 2020-08-01 | 14 | Up-to-date |
| Sam | 2020-10-20 | 2020-08-05 | 65 | Requires Screening |
| Dan | 2020-11-05 | 2020-08-05 | 90 | No Screening Required |
| Mike | 2020-08-20 | 2020-08-01 | 14 | No Screening Required |

```
mutate_function <- function(df, new_col, my_col, my_col2, value1, value2, value3) {
    
    df %>% mutate(new_col = case_when(
             my_col <= 14 ~ "value1",
             my_col <= 14 & my_col2 != "TypeX" ~ "value2",
             (my_col > 14 & my_col <= 65) ~ "value3",
             TRUE ~ "value2")
    )}

mutate_function(df, Action, mycol = screen2enroll_days, my_col2 = enrollment_type, "Up-to-date", "Requires Screening", "No Screening Required")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: and please share some data;   use   dput(yourdata) and paste the output in your edited question

Comment: @BillO'Brien: I added the info you requested. It was posted prematurely. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a number of things to address to make this functional:

- Inside a function you can dynamically access column names from your arguments with double curly braces (`{{...}}`). Alternatively, use can use the bang-bang operator with `sym`: `!!sym()`. Or, try `.data[[variable]]` to reference the variable from the pipe. Otherwise, it would seem you are trying to reference a column called `my_col` or `my_col2` (for example) from `df` which don't exist.
- If you want to set the new column values based on the `value1` `value2` or `value3` arguments, you will want to leave off the quotes in your `case_when` statement
- To dynamically set the `new_col`, use assignment (`:=`)
- When calling the function, you may want to double check your argument names (such as `mycol` vs. `my_col` - note underscore)
- Finally, you may want to double check your `case_when` logic. I believe the second line might never get called, as all circumstances when `my_col` is <= 14 will be considered as `value1`

---

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_function <- function(df, new_col, my_col, my_col2, value1, value2, value3) {
  df %>% mutate({{new_col}} := case_when(
    {{my_col}} <= 14 ~ value1,
    {{my_col}} <= 14 & {{my_col2}} != "TypeX" ~ value2,
    ({{my_col}} > 14 & {{my_col}} <= 65) ~ value3,
    TRUE ~ value2)
  )
}

mutate_function(df, 
                new_col = "Action", 
                my_col = "screen2enroll_days", 
                my_col2 = "enrollment_type", 
                "Up-to-date", 
                "Requires Screening", 
                "No Screening Required")
```